# How to make a Readonly expandable properties in the winforms PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid

I am working on a winforms application that uses the standard winforms property grid in a fairly involved way.

I provides custom type descriptors and type converters for class and also specified if certain properties are to be readonly, and not editable in the property grid.

I am having problems determining how to have an expandable type that is also readonly - in the documentation it seems that overriding  `public bool IsReadOnly` is the way to go but as soon as I specify in the type converter that there are child properties it stops working.

I have managed to distill my code to a small example:

Here is the custom object:

```
public sealed class TestNode : ICustomTypeDescriptor
{
    private readonly bool _isEditable;
    private readonly List<TestNode> _childNodes = new List<TestNode>();

    public TestNode(string name, bool isEditable = true)
    {
        _isEditable = isEditable;
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public bool IsEditable
    {
        get { return _isEditable; }
    }

    public List<TestNode> ChildNodes
    {
        get { return _childNodes; }
    }

    public void AddChild(TestNode testNode)
    {
        ChildNodes.Add(testNode);
    }


    #region ICustomTypeDescriptor

    public AttributeCollection GetAttributes()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(this, true);
    }

    public string GetClassName()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetClassName(this, true);
    }

    public string GetComponentName()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetComponentName(this, true);
    }

    public TypeConverter GetConverter()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(this, true);
    }

    public EventDescriptor GetDefaultEvent()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetDefaultEvent(this, true);
    }

    public PropertyDescriptor GetDefaultProperty()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public EventDescriptorCollection GetEvents()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetEvents(this, true);
    }

    public EventDescriptorCollection GetEvents(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetEvents(this, attributes, true);
    }

    public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties()
    {
        return GetProperties(new Attribute[0]);
    }

    public object GetEditor(Type editorBaseType)
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetEditor(this, editorBaseType, true);
    }

    public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(new PropertyDescriptor[]{new TestNodeDescriptor(this)}, true);
    }

    public object GetPropertyOwner(PropertyDescriptor pd)
    {
        return this;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Which has a descriptor like this, where I can specify if it shows as readonly in the propertyGrid:

```
public class TestNodeDescriptor : PropertyDescriptor
{
    private readonly TestNode _testNode;

    public TestNodeDescriptor(TestNode testNode) : base("Test", null)
    {
        _testNode = testNode;
    }

    public override bool CanResetValue(object component)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public override object GetValue(object component)
    {
        return _testNode;
    }

    public override void ResetValue(object component)
    {
    }

    public override void SetValue(object component, object value)
    {
    }

    public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public override Type ComponentType
    {
        get { return null; }
    }

    public override bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return !_testNode.IsEditable; }
    }

    public override Type PropertyType
    {
        get { return typeof(TestNode); }
    }

    public override TypeConverter Converter
    {
        get
        {
            return new TestTypeConverter(_testNode);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the type converter, where I specify the conversion to string for display and the required expandable type converter to show child properties:

```
public class TestTypeConverter : ExpandableObjectConverter
{
    private readonly TestNode _testNode;

    public TestTypeConverter(TestNode testNode)
    {
        _testNode = testNode;
    }

    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
    {
        return destinationType == typeof(string);
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        return _testNode.Name;
    }

    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(ITypeDescriptorContext context, object value, Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        var descriptors = _testNode.ChildNodes.Select(c => (PropertyDescriptor) (new TestNodeDescriptor(c))).ToArray();
        return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(descriptors);
    }

    public override bool GetPropertiesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return _testNode.ChildNodes.Any();
    }
}
```

The odd thing is that if the method in the type converter `public override bool GetPropertiesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)`  return true then the children are shown as expected but its not as readonly.

For example with this test code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    readonly TestNode _parentNode = new TestNode("Parent");
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var child1 = new TestNode("Child1", false);

        var child2 = new TestNode("Child2", false);
        child2.AddChild(new TestNode("Grandchild", false));

        _parentNode.AddChild(child2);
        _parentNode.AddChild(child1);



        propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = _parentNode;
    }
}
```

I would get a dialog show like this:

[image]

I was expecting all child nodes to be readonly.  Has anyone got something like this to work successfully with the PropertyGrid?

Its been a very frustrating experience and any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Parents have black color, but they are read-only. For those cells, being read-only is controlled by `CanConvertFrom` which returns `false` by default when the `sourceType` is `string`.

Comment: Not sure you can work around that. As soon as a TypeConverter returns true to the GetPropertiesSupported method (this is the case for ExpandableObjectConverter, or derivated, but it works with any TypeConverter), than it's not displayed as a grayed item. That doesn't mean it's not readonly, it's just shown like that, meaning it has sub properties. A grayed item means it's "disabled" for UI, not "readonly".

Comment: @RezaAghaei This was the problem it seems, as soon as I put the CanConvert from implementation it displayed it greyed out like I wanted it, however the child properties still needed to be manually set to readonly they didn't inherit it - which I kind of expected it.  Thanks.

Comment: @SimonMourier Yes its a precision I should've added, I could prevent the properties being written to again but it was the display issue of not being greyed out that I couldn't solve